# How to express mixed logistic regression in formal notation?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis

I'm working with `glmer` in the `lme4` package in `R` to estimate a binary outcome variable from two categorical predictors (with 3 levels each) as well as two random effects parameters. The data I'm trying to predict are binary outcome data generated by an experimental design in which multiple participants (`Subject`) completed multiple test items (`Item`). I allow only intercepts to vary randomly by `Subject`, and allow slopes for `X1`, (but not `X2`) and intercepts to vary by `Item`. I also include an interaction term for the two three-level categorical predictors. In other words, my `glmer` formula is:

```
~ X1 * X2 + (1 + X1|Item) + (1 | Subject)
```

My question is: how do I correctly represent this model formula as an equation?

I have read @BenBolker's recommendations on model specification, [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification). The closest model specification to mine given there is this:

```
∼ X + (1 + X∣Subject) + (1∣Item)
```

...and the recommended equation to represent it is given as:

$(\beta_0+b_{S,0s}+b_{I,0i})+(\beta_1+b_{S,1s})X_i + e_{si}$

where $b_{S,0s}$ represents random intercepts for `Subject`, $b_{I,0i}$ represents random intercepts for `Item` and $b_{S,1s}$ the random slope increment for $\beta_1$.

Based on this formula, I've tried to express my model as follows:

$
log(p_{si}/(1-p_{si})) = \\ 
(\beta_0 + b_{S,0s} + b_{I,0i}) + \\ 
(\beta_{1} + bl1_{I,1i})X1lev1_s + \\ 
(\beta_{2} + bl2_{I,1i})X1lev2_s  + \\ 
\beta_{3}X2lev1_s +\\ 
\beta_{4}X2lev2_s+\\ 
\beta_{5}X1lev1:X2lev1_{s}+\\
\beta_{6}X1lev1:X2lev2_{s}+\\ 
\beta_{7}X1lev2:X2lev1_{s}+\\ 
\beta_{8}X1lev2:X2lev2_{s}
$

Where $_s$ and $_i$ index `Subject` and `Item`, respectively, and random intercepts for these terms are represented by $b_{S,0s}$ and $b_{I,0i}$. The random slopes for each level of `X1` are represented by $bl1_{I,1i}$ and $bl2_{I,1i}$, i.e. $l$ stands for each level. Finally, I include fixed effects for `X2` with no random slope component, as well as the 2x2 interaction terms between each of the levels of `X1` and `X2`.

My question is, is this correct? If not I'm hoping someone could please explain why as well as provide the correct equation.

Comment: A nice blog post on mixed modelling as a foreign language: https://thestudyofthehousehold.me/2018/02/28/2018-02-28-formulae-are-a-lot-like-french-slang/.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your time and attention:)

Comment: Well, I found Bolker's recommendation from that blog post, and I think they certainly were helpful. Thanks.

Comment: At least something I recommended was helpful! I’ll settle for that. 

Comment: You've been very helpful, it's just that the question wasn't about experimental design:)

Comment: Seems like it's gone dead... Are you sure, @IsabellaGhement, that you wouldn't be kind enough to provide an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation seems correct; I would write something like:
$$
\begin{align}
\log \left(\frac{p_{si}}{1-p_{si}}\right) =  & \,\,  \beta_0 + b_{S,0s} + b_{I,0i} \\ 
& + (\beta_{1} + b_{I,1i}) \cdot X1_1  + (\beta_{2} + b_{I,2i}) \cdot X1_2  \\ 
& + \beta_{3} \cdot X2_2 + \beta_{4} \cdot X2_2 \\ 
& + \beta_{5} \cdot X1_1:X2_1 + \beta_{6} \cdot X1_1:X2_2\\ 
& + \beta_{7} \cdot X1_2:X2_1 + \beta_{8} \cdot X1_2:X2_2
& \end{align}
$$

The only part that is missing to fully specify the model are the distribution of the random effects:

$$
b_S \sim \mathcal{N} \left(0, \sigma_S^2 \right) \\
{\bf b}_I \sim \mathcal{N} \left(0, \Omega \right)
$$
where $\Omega$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects, e.g.

$$
{\bf b}_I = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{b_0}}\\
{{b_1}}\\
b_2
\end{array}} \right] \sim\cal N \left( {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}} \right],\Omega  = \left[ 
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\sigma_0^2}&{{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_0},{b_1}} \right) } & {{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_0},{b_2}} \right) }\\
{{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_0},{b_1}} \right)}&{\sigma _1^2}& {{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_1},{b_2}} \right) } \\ {{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_0},{b_2}} \right)}& {{\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{b_1},{b_2}} \right) } & {\sigma _2^2}
\end{array}} 
\right]} \right)
$$
(where I simplified the notation in the subscripts for clarity).

Comment: Thanks so much!